# Selecting first available number not in reserved ranges

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `boxes` and `companies`. Every box that belongs to some company is added to the same store (defined by field store_id) and has unique number in that store, and every company can have reserved range for boxes (fields boxes_from and boxes_to in table companies).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boxes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `boxes` (`id`, `store_id`, `number`) VALUES
(1, 1, 5),
(2, 1, 6),
(3, 1, 7),
(4, 1, 8),
(5, 1, 9),
(6, 1, 10),
(7, 1, 1),
(8, 1, 2),
(9, 1, 3);

+----+----------+--------+
| id | store_id | number |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |      5 |
|  2 |        1 |      6 |
|  3 |        1 |      7 |
|  4 |        1 |      8 |
|  5 |        1 |      9 |
|  6 |        1 |     10 |
|  7 |        1 |      1 |
|  8 |        1 |      2 |
|  9 |        1 |      3 |
+----+----------+--------+

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `boxes_from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `boxes_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `companies` (`id`, `boxes_from`, `boxes_to`, `store_id`) VALUES
(1, 5, 10, 1),
(2, 0, 0, 1),
(3, 15, 20, 1);

+----+------------+----------+----------+
| id | boxes_from | boxes_to | store_id |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
|  1 |          5 |       10 |        1 |
|  2 |          0 |        0 |        1 |
|  3 |         15 |       20 |        1 |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
```

If there are no available numbers in a range reserved for some company, I need to find first available number for a new box.

For instance, if there are two reserved ranges, 5-10 and 15-20, and there are already boxes with numbers 1-3, first available number is 4. If there are boxes with numbers 1-4, next available number is 11, after first reserved range.

I came to a solution where I find all possible next numbers and then I have to cross join that result with table companies to filter out reserved ranges.

```
SELECT number, COUNT(number) as cnt 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as number FROM boxes WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT number FROM boxes WHERE store_id=1 AND number=1) 
    UNION 
    SELECT t1.number+1 as number FROM boxes t1 LEFT JOIN boxes t2 ON t2.number=t1.number+1 WHERE t1.store_id=1 AND t2.number IS NULL
    UNION 
    SELECT boxes_to+1 as number FROM companies WHERE store_id=1 AND boxes_from>0 AND boxes_to>0 AND boxes_to+1 NOT IN (
        SELECT number FROM boxes WHERE store_id=1)
    ) n, companies 
    WHERE number NOT BETWEEN boxes_from AND boxes_to GROUP BY number HAVING cnt=(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM companies
)
```

This query returns all available next numbers:

```
+--------+-----+
| number | cnt |
+--------+-----+
|      4 |   3 |
|     11 |   3 |
|     21 |   3 |
+--------+-----+
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: Your answer seems like a good one.

Comment: Since I am a php programmer, not sql expert, I doubt I found the most optimal solution. I wonder if there is other way to filter out numbers in reserved ranges than cross joining with companies table and counting results.